# Firefox can't handle my jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm working on a portfolio for myself. The site works fabulous in chrome, safari and even in latest IE. Firefox however seems to "dodge" my code. It's really hard to describe, but if you open the same site in both browsers the menu scrolls ain't working, the projects cannot be open and in the bottom the input fields seems to be broken too (however the inputs are okay when removing the style).

I have tried to change jquery version, rearrange my script and even reinstalling firefox. Nothing seems to work. I am going crazy about this.

Have anyone encountered this problem before? How did you solve it?

The website url is: http://eugan.com

Comment: You have to pass the event to prevent `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scrollTo` function is defined like so:

```
function scrollTo(id)
{
  // Scroll
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');

}
```

and you call it like so:

```
$('.welcome').click(function(e){ 
  scrollTo('welcome');
});
```

As you can see, you're passing in `'welcome'` or another string, yet within the `scrollTo` function you try to call `event.preventDefault()`.

If you were to change `scrollTo` to the following:

```
function scrollTo(event, id)
{
  // Scroll
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');

}
```

and the way you call it to:

```
$('.welcome').click(function(e){ 
  scrollTo(e, 'welcome');
});
```

You should have more luck.

I'm not sure what your problem with the inputs is, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you so much for this informative solution! It works perfect. The inputs I solved myself by removing padding and adding height. This seems to fix that.

However, the project is not working to open. I think it might be the same problem. Will try to add something similare to my "openPage"-script.

Answer (score 1):

You have this function in your JavaScript

```
function scrollTo(id)
{
  // Scroll
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');

}
```

**event** is **undefined** when this function is fired, so the way that this is invoked is *not* correct.. You can see this in the `Console` tab of the F12 tools with the error "ReferenceError: event is not defined"

Firefox does not help you out in this situation by allowing the rest of the code to execute. The other browsers obviously do.

You need to refactor this JavaScript function and then it should come together!

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed the errors in console. :)

Comment: No worries! Good luck with the fix!

Answer (score 0):

Nice site. What's happening is your links with `href='#'` are breaking your scrolling actions.

This is normal behavior for a browser to scroll to the top when you click a link with `href='#'`.

You need to disable this default event, and could do so by adding `e.preventDefault()` to all of your `.click()` bindings, on your links.

Something like this before you initialize all your `.click()` bindings, should do the trick.

```
$("a[href='#']").each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(e){e.preventDefault()});
});
```